# How to create an API token in Python for GitHub

Tags: python, http, github

I want to download a zip file from my private repository from GitHub. Ths is my link to my private GitHub repository

```
https://<TOKEN>@raw.githubusercontent.com/<NAME>/Folder/master/dataset.zip
```

Unfortunately I get an `HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found`, so also in Python. I want to get access and download it in Python. I used a Personal access token for that.

I read that you can get access to GitHub and download files with an API? Could you please help me to get access to my GitHub an download the zip file? Is there a option to get the raw data from my private GitHub repository with `OAuth Token`? I also found a libary https://github.com/sigmavirus24/github3.py or all libaries https://developer.github.com/v3/libraries/#python

I only need a URL

```
# GitHub Access
file_url= ("<URL>")
zipped_file = keras.utils.get_file("dataset", file_url, extract=False)
print(zipped_file)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe too late but If you don't solved this yet (or could be useful for future viewers) you could use [PyGithub](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub) with a [personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token).

```
import urllib
from github import Github

# Create a Github instance with an access token
g = Github("your-personal-access-token")

# Get repository by name:
repo = g.get_repo("org/repo-name")

# Get a specific content file:
contents = repo.get_contents("your-file")

# Donwnload file form ContenFile object info:
urllib.urlretrieve(contents.download_url, "name-for-your-file")
```

`contents` is an instance of [ContentFile](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github_objects/ContentFile.html) which represents [contents from the GitHub API](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/repos#contents), then you can access to the `.download_url` property which is a string similar like this:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/org/repo-name/default-branch-name/your-file?token=your-personal-access-token
```